# Склонение названий улиц

Tags: грамотная-речь

Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно произносить название улицы в предложении: "Я иду по улице Лермонтова"? А как правильно сказать в том случае, когда говоришь быстро и коротко без употребления самого слова "улица": "Я иду по Лермонтова"? Или как-то по-другому? Мне хочется сказать так же, как "по Советской")

Comment: По-моему, все так и говорят - по Лермонтова, по Советской, (по Абрикосовой, на Виноградную, на Тенистой :) ). Не думаю, что это регулируется какими-то формальными правилами, но могу ошибаться.

Comment: По Абрикосовой понятно, а по Лермонтовой можно сказать?

Comment: Если бы улица называлась Лермонтовая, тогда по Лермонтовой. Да, так и говорят, например: "Магазин на Ленина", "Иду по Ворошилова".

Comment: @Алла Нет, режет же слух. Иду по Пушкина, живу на Кирова. Видимо, мы мысленно подсталяем - по (улице) Пушкина и т.д. С другой стороны у нас в городе есть улица Свободы. Все говорят "по Свободе", "на Свободе", никто не скажет "на Свободы", потому что это звучит ужасно. Плюсанул вопрос, забавно))

Comment: Спасибо всем! В последнем случае вот именно со словом "улица"  произносится " по улице  Свободы ", а без слова  "улица"  уже говорится " по Свободе".

Comment: Ответы нужно давать в ответах.

Answer (score 1):

Не бывает двух улиц — Лермонтовская ул. и ул. Лермонтова, — и свою единственную жители будут называть и так и эдак: ошибки в передаче информации не будет. Вот в мегаполисе немного сложнее: надо быть внимательней, не посылая приезжего в Черкизово, где ул. Лермонтова, или Косино, где Лермонтовский проспект (метро «Лермонтовская»), если ему нужно быть на Лермонтовской площади, где дерево и человек в пальто.

Так что — *шагаю* *по Лермонтова* / *по Лермонтовской* или *Лермонтовскому*.